# 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint in Magento2.4.5

Tags: compiler-errors, magento2.4

I am trying to run magento project on local.

so I extracted sql and cloned magento project.

After I installed composer, I run `bin/magento upgrade`, but I got error like this.

[image]

what is the issue?